# println! panics when called concurrently

Tags: rust

I am trying to handle some *nix signals and have the following code:

```
// nix = "0.8.0"
extern crate nix;

use nix::sys::signal::{SaFlags, SigAction, sigaction, SIGINT, SigSet};
use nix::sys::signal::SigHandler::Handler;

extern fn interrupted(_:i32) {
    println!("Interrupted");
}

fn main() {
    let sigact = SigAction::new(Handler(interrupted), SaFlags::empty(), SigSet::thread_get_mask().unwrap());

    if let Err(_) = unsafe { sigaction(SIGINT, &sigact) } {
        println!("Failed to register handler");
        std::process::exit(1);
    }

    loop {
        println!("Hello");
    }
}
```

I thought `println!()` could be called concurrently, however this code always panics when I interrupt

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'already borrowed: BorrowMutError', /checkout/src/libcore/result.rs:859
stack backtrace:
   [...]
  10: <std::io::stdio::StdoutLock<'a> as std::io::Write>::write
             at /checkout/src/libcore/result.rs:761
             at /checkout/src/libcore/cell.rs:670
             at /checkout/src/libstd/io/stdio.rs:466
  11: std::io::Write::write_all
             at /checkout/src/libstd/io/mod.rs:957
  12: <std::io::Write::write_fmt::Adaptor<'a, T> as core::fmt::Write>::write_str
             at /checkout/src/libstd/io/mod.rs:1017
  13: core::fmt::write
             at /checkout/src/libcore/fmt/mod.rs:969
  14: <std::io::stdio::Stdout as std::io::Write>::write_fmt
             at /checkout/src/libstd/io/mod.rs:1028
             at /checkout/src/libstd/io/stdio.rs:460
  15: std::io::stdio::_print
             at /checkout/src/libstd/io/stdio.rs:680
  16: signals::interrupted
             at ./Rust/signals/src/main.rs:8
   [...]
```

The documentation for `println!()` does not specifically mention any panics for concurrent execution but just that it panics when it cannot write to stdout. I am slightly confused by this panic, as calling `println!()` from multiple threads in a loop works fine.

Is the problem that `println!()` is thread-safe, but not safe on the same thread, i.e. having some thread local static dependencies that are violated when the first instance of `println!()` in `main` is interrupted and the second instance in `interrupted` is called on the same thread, or how can I imagine this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the problem that `println!()` is thread-safe, but not safe on the same thread, i.e. having some thread local static dependencies that are violated when the first instance of `println!()` in `main` is interrupted and the second instance in `interrupted` is called on the same thread [...]?

Yes, that's about right.

The [`println!()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/05b5797664d6aeaa0c7d0606610f336fe0b57e97/src/libstd/macros.rs#L127-L131) macro delegates to [`print!()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/05b5797664d6aeaa0c7d0606610f336fe0b57e97/src/libstd/macros.rs#L100-L102), which calls [`std::io::_print`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/05b5797664d6aeaa0c7d0606610f336fe0b57e97/src/libstd/io/stdio.rs#L700-L702), which calls `print_to` by passing `&LOCAL_STDOUT` as an argument. `LOCAL_STDOUT` is defined like this:

```
/// Stdout used by print! and println! macros
thread_local! {
    static LOCAL_STDOUT: RefCell<Option<Box<Write + Send>>> = {
        RefCell::new(None)
    }
}
```

The panic you're seeing comes from the [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) used by `LOCAL_STDOUT`. Signal handlers run on the thread that receives the signal. Thus, when a signal is emitted, the signal handler may run while the `RefCell` is borrowed mutably. Since `RefCell` only allows one mutable borrow at a time, attempting to use `println!()` in a signal handler may panic.

Comment: You may want to point out that the signal handler is actually executed in the same OS-thread that `main` runs in. The `RefCell` successfully prevents horrible concurrency bugs here by noticing two concurrent write accesses that made it past the lock on stdout.

One can't access stdout in the signal handler, not even in Rust. If you need to really, really need to print in the signal handler, you need to queue up a message and print from another thread. But beware kids: While you hold the lock on the queue, another signal may interrupt you, deadlocking you on the queue.

Comment: @user2722968 Regarding "not even in Rust", can't you just use C's `write()` to print a constant string to `stdout` in a signal handler as `write()` is signal-safe? I just tried `let msg: &str = "Interrupted"; write(1, msg.as_ptr(), msg.len());` instead of `println!()` and it seems to be working fine

Comment: AFAICS there is nothing protecting that write from getting interrupted by another signal mid-flight, giving you "InterruInterruptedted"